# Two different values from the same kSecAttrAccount in Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am really puzzled by this.

I have a class which initializes like this:

```
class MyClass {
  let storage = Storage.sharedService

  static let sharedInstance = MyClass()
  fileprivate init() {
    storage.dumpKeychain()
    v1 = storage.loadNonimportantValue()
    print("V1: \(v1 ?? "nil")")
    v2 = storage.loadImportantValue()
    print("V2: \(v2 ?? "nil")")
  }
}
```

storage.dumpKeychain() is function (taken from internet) that prints content of the Keychain accessible to my app

```
func dumpKeychain() {
  let query: [String: Any] = [
    kSecClass as String : kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecReturnData as String  : kCFBooleanFalse!,
    kSecReturnAttributes as String : kCFBooleanTrue!,
    kSecReturnRef as String : kCFBooleanTrue!,
    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll
  ]

  var result: AnyObject?

  let lastResultCode = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
    SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
  }

  var values = [String:String]()
  if lastResultCode == noErr {
    let array = result as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
    for item in array! {
      if let key = item[kSecAttrAccount as String] as? String, let value = item[kSecValueData as String] as? Data {
        values[key] = String(data: value, encoding:.utf8)
      }
    }
  }
  print(values)
}
```

And storage.loadImportantValue() is function that loads a value from given kSecAttrAccount ("Important")

```
fileprivate func loadImportantValue() -> String? {

  var readQuery : [String : Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrAccount as String: "Important",
    kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue!
  ]

  var storedData : AnyObject?
  _ = SecItemCopyMatching(readQuery as CFDictionary, &storedData);

  return String(data: storedData as? Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

What I see in the logs is that dumpKeychain returns:

```
[..., "Nonimportant": "correct value", "Important": "correct value", ...]
```

And the line print(value) in MyClass initializer prints:

```
V1: "correct value"
V2: "incorrect value"
```

How is it possible that these two calls made almost one after another return two different values from the same spot in Keychain for V2 and at the same time V1 is ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
There really are two different values of the data.

This class is part of a framework which after updating was doing this. It is so that the prior version of framework was using another framework to manage keychain and that framework stored data with more attributes then my new version. And what I thought was replacing the data was actually adding new entry with less attributes.

So at the end after running the legacy code and then updating it with newer version there were two entries of the data at the "same" key.